# Length of optimal Huffman and arithmetic coding

Tags: entropy, huffman-coding

I'm new to this page and I used the search function, but did not find the exact question. I'm asking here because my classmates and I have been wondering about this, but did not find an answer.

I have learned about Huffman coding and arithmetic coding in a CS course and I believed that given word occurences of $2^{-k}$, they should provide results of the same length and be optimal.

I have a word to encode, explicitly by hand (and calculator): <strike>**Lana**</strike> **Nala**, using Huffman encoding and arithmetic encoding.

This means the following probabilities:
**a: 0.5** ($\frac{1}{2^1}$) -- **L: 0.25** ($\frac{1}{2^2}$) -- **n: 0.25** ($\frac{1}{2^1}$)

With the Huffman algorithm, I get:

N: $\frac{1}{4}$; l: $\frac{1}{4}$; a: $\frac{1}{2}$

N, l: $\frac{1}{2}$; a: $\frac{1}{2}$.

N, l, a: 1.

--> for example:  N: 00 ; a: 1 ; l: 10

This gives us an encoding for "Nala": 001101

---

Now, I'm doing it with the Arithmetic encoding algorithm the way I learned it:

Alphabetical order of the letters: a: 0.5; l: 0.25; N: 0.25.

We divide the interval between 0 and 1 in these proportions.
**a: [0; 0,5[** ; **b: [0.5; 0.75[** ; **N: [0.75; 1[**

We first want “N”, so we choose the N interval and the next intervals are:
**a: [0.75; 0.875[** ; **l: [0.875 ; 0.9375[** ; **N: [0.9375 ; 1[**

Because of the following “a”, divide the “a”-Interval:
a: [0.75; 0.8125[ ; l: [0.8125; 0.84375[ ; N: [0.84375; 0.875[

The “l” in “Nala” gives us:
**a: [0.8125; 0.828125[** ; **l: [0.828125; 0.8359375]** ;  **N: [0.8359375: 0.84375[**

Because of Nal-a, we want our binary code to represent a number in the "last a-interval":
**[0.8125; 0.828125[**.

1101 lands us exactly on the lower bound of this interval: $1*0.5 + 1*0.25 + 0*0.125 + 1*0.0625 = 0.8125$.

My classmates got the same results and as far as we know, they are correct.

However, I do not understand why Huffman coding and arithmetic coding yield results of different lengths: 6 binary digits vs. 4 binary digits (1101) in spite of probabilities that follow a distribution of $\frac{1}{2^k}$.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Happenstance for a message ending with the symbol assigned the interval starting at 0? Without further indication of message length, you can't tell "Lan" from "Lanaaa". (Where did "Nala" come from?)

Comment: Thank you! Oh my, of course I have always meant "Nala", not Lana.

Comment: Did you check the [Arithmetic coding#Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding#Huffman_coding) article on Wikipedia?

Comment: Thank you, yes, I did and that's why we started wondering in the first place. The article states that "By contrast, using the extension of Huffman coding (to strings) does not reach entropy unless all probabilities of alphabet symbols are powers of two, in which case both Huffman and arithmetic coding achieve entropy. "
In my example, the probabilities are powers of two (2^-1 and 2^-2), but arithmetic coding seems to excel.